# I got GCM Error - MismatchedSenderID.

Tags: java, php, android, google-cloud-messaging

I am sending GCM notification to device1 from device2 and then device2 sends an acknowledgement to device again using GCM. But when I had the API key as server key then device2 could not send acknowledgement and in log cat device2 showed error "MismatchedSenderID" .

I fixed it by using "browser key" on device2. Here I had to use "browser key" since it was not working with server key . Now My question is : Why it is working with "browser key" not with "server key" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its good if Above solution is working for you ,but according to my opinion ,you should use server key on server side (e.g webservices) ,android key on Android apps .

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow; it is nice to answer to an old question; please, give a little more details in your answer however. Your answer is very short and it isn't obvious if it really brings anything new.

Answer (score 0):

It should work with "server key" as well as with "browser key " . But in some cases if any one of them is not working then you should try another one .[See here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/phonegap/articles/android-push-notifications-with-phonegap.html)